# Reference method and class of exception (c#, .net)

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have a class with a method and I want to throw an exception within the method. In this I would like to reference the method and class in which the exception was thrown to find the source of the error more easily.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        (..)
        Throw new Exception("An error occurred. Method:" + ?? + ", Class:" + ?? +");
    }
```

Comment: You know that exceptions have stack traces that tell where they were thrown, right?  You don't need to recreate that in your exception message, the exception message should explain what happened to cause an exception, not where.

Comment: all this info is included in stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually already have all that information and just need to access it via the Exception's [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace.aspx) property with something like:

```
        try
        {
            // to do something exceptional
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }
```

This sample just write to std out but you could do anything with the StackTrace information you want, including logging it to file or db.

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to do that. Look at the `StackTrace` property of the exception in your `try-catch` block.

Answer (score 2):

That information will already be in the stack trace. There's no need to include it in the message as well.

If you absolutely *have* to, there's [`MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getcurrentmethod.aspx). For the class, would you want the class of the execution-time object on which the method was called, or the method which is actually executing? (I would stick to the stack trace though...)

Comment: I want to have exactly this "SomeMethod" because this is where the problem occurred.

Comment: @Jan-Frederik: But you asked for the *class* as well. That's what I was questioning in terms of precise behaviour. It's all moot anyway, as you should just use the stack trace...

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) class for that.